# The Value Of A Check Box Is Empty Using An Enumeration Inside A Repeater (ASP.NET Web Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a repeater and I set the value of an html check box control with the
value of an enumeration instead of hard-coding a magic number. When I try to
access the html check box control in the repeater's ItemCreated event handler,
the value is an empty string. Why is this and how can I fix it?

C# Code

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var myObject = e.Item.DataItem as MyObject;
    if (myObject != null)
    {
        var checkBox = e.Item.FindControl("checkbox1") as HtmlInputCheckBox         

        // The value is empty!
        var value = checkBox.Value;
    }
}
```

Not Working

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>      
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value='<%# SomeEnum.Value %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Working

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>      
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Try tapping into OnItemDataBound instead.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks Adam! What happened is that I selected ItemCreated by accident instead of ItemDataBound (they are right next to each other in intellisense). I had a hunch it had something to do with the control's life cycle, but I didn't see that I had the wrong event wired up! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemCreated` is triggered before `ItemDataBound` and also on every postback to recreate he controls even when the Repater is not databound again. So i would not use ItemCreated if you need to access the `DataSource` of any [databound WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) like `Repeater`.

Apart from that, make the checkbox `runat=server`(or use a ASP.NET `CheckBox`) if you want to `find` it on the server.